# why is my app showing ads only on my phone that i use to test it but not in other devices, even thou i have published it on play store

Tags: admob

This App is showing real ads on the phone I use to test it, but its not showing ads in every other device. I have removed the addTestDevice(), I have published the app on play store and the adUnit is active in admob. Here is my gradle file apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.samkecy.naitesapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at your question and fix the formatting

Comment: Ok sir sir thanks, I'm just a newbie